# New Beracha on Mezuzah After Summer Vacation?

Tags: mezuzah

The [Pischei Teshuva YD (291:4)](https://www.sefaria.org/Pitchei_Teshuva_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.291.4?vhe=Ashlei_Ravrevei:_Shulchan_Aruch_Yoreh_Deah,_Lemberg,_1888&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) seems to say that one might need to make a new beracha on the home mezuzah after returning from a vacation.

> ועוד נ"ל דגם ההולך מביתו על איזה ימים דלכאורה הדין דכשחוזר לביתו יברך
> על המצוה דהא בנתיים שלא היה בדירת ביתו לא היה עליו חובת מזוזה ומתחיל
> עתה חיוב חדש כו' (ועיין בנ"צ מ"ש בזה) ושוב הביא בשם ס' בר"י בא"ח סימן
> י"ט שכתב בפשיטות בדין הראשון דשוכר בית שיש בו מזוזה דאינו מברך דלא
> תקנו הברכה רק על שעת קביעת המזוזה. וממילא גם בדין הב' בנוסע מעירו
> ואח"כ חוזר לביתו אינו מברך וסיים דצ"ע לדינא ע"ש

Do any Poskim disagree with this and say there is no need to make a new beracha when returning home or this is what we are supposed to do after every trip?

Comment: see magen avraham https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%99%D7%98_%D7%90 and r akiva eiger

Comment: Even your source isn't sure to do this, so safek brachot would rule against it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a teshuva of [R' Akiva Eiger](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14656&st=&pgnum=18) (siman 9 ד"ה ונ"ל at the end of the left column) who goes so far as to say that someone who goes on a shopping trip for a few hours would have to make a new brocha when they return. However, many people argue on him based on several rishonim in Bava Metzia and Menachos who hold that the chiyuv mezuzah doesn't go away so easily.

In the Mechon Hame'or edition of the teshuva, they bring the following people who argue on R' Akiva Eiger (I haven't seen them inside, feel free to look them up): Shu"t Ein Yitzhak chelek 1 Y"D siman 31; Dvar Avraham chelek 1 siman 37 at the end in the hagaha; shu"t Toafos Re'em siman 43, see Tzemach Dovid; see Pnei Aryeh (by R' Aryeh Halevi, Vilna תרל"ג) page 4a an onwards.